# How to execute blender from python?

Tags: python

I am using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/what-is-anaconda/) 3 and I want to know how to execute blender from python.
Since python can be called from inside blender so it has to be possible vice versa. Does anyone know how to do this? Please help me by providing the procedure for setting up the environment for this.

Comment: Apparently it is possible to use Blender as a Python module, though it seems you need to build it yourself. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule explains how to build and install the module. Unfortunately, I've not found help on how to actually use it once it's installed.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to start Blender.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["/path/to/blender", "somefile.blend"])
```

> Since python can be called from inside blender so it has to be possible vice versa.

This is not a very logical statement. Just because Blender embeds Python doesn't mean anything when it comes to starting Blender from Python.